# How to run only 1 window in Xorg?

Tags: server, xorg, desktop-environments, xserver

I don't want to use a desktop environment because I don't want to waste the CPU. I want to run Chromium browser without a desktop environment. I know there's already a question like this (it was about Firefox). I followed that question and it installed Vanilla GNOME after I installed Xorg. Is it possible to run Xorg with ONLY Chromium Browser WITHOUT a login screen e. g. using the *startx* command?
Also, will WebGL still work without a desktop environment?

**Ubuntu version:** 20.04

**Type of installation:** Server

Comment: It's totally possible to run an app without a DE.  From my understanding there is a whole reddit post dedicated to people using windows managers like i3wm, etc to achieve their goal.  https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/  I would actually recommend a test environment first like a VM just to kind of help get an idea of what you are going to do.

Comment: Ok.. how can I install Xorg without any desktop environment? I tried apt install xorg and it installed vanilla GNOME

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/663803/289128

Answer (score -1):

ye u can run stuff w/out de or wm
just run startx xterm and type the command to open chromium in xterm
a window should show up

for webGL, idk but it should cuz even minecraft works
i only know this cuz bspwm wont run and i just wanna do normal stuff lol